# Convergence of $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\exp(\frac{(-1)^n}{n})-1\right)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Consider the series
>   $
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n
> $ where
>   $$
> a_n:=\left(\exp\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right)-1\right). 
> $$
>   Show that it is convergent but not absolutely convergent.

---

I tried the alternating test but I'm not sure if $\{|a_n|\}$ is decreasing or not. And I don't see how other tests might help. Any ideas?

---

[**Disclaimer**: this question, asked on Jan 9 '14 at 16:01, is NOT a duplicate of the [linked one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1366873/9464), which was asked much later on Jul 19 '15 at 20:32]

Comment: Can you show that $a_n\mp 1/n$ is bounded by $1/n^2$, whose sum is absolutely convergent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recalling the Taylor series of $e^x$, we have

> $$ e^{\frac{(-1)^n}{n}}-1 \sim \frac{(-1)^n}{n}=b_n$$

and $\sum b_n $ is conditionally convergent.

**Note:**

> $$ e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\dots \implies e^x -1 = x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\dots \implies e^x-1\sim x.  $$

Comment: How can I formalize it? I asked a question related to my concerns about formalization of this idea: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2849127/is-this-use-of-big-o-notation-for-proving-convergence-correct/2849610

Comment: Asymptotic equality is insufficient. For $$a_n = \exp \biggl(\frac{(-1)^n}{n} + \frac{1}{n\log (n+1)}\biggr) - 1$$ we'd also have $a_n \sim b_n$, but in that case $\sum a_n$ would diverge. It is necessary to bound $a_n - \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ to conclude.