# Show that the series $\sum(\exp(\frac{(-1)^n}{n})-1)$converges, but not absolutely.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, exponential-function

> Show that the series converges, but not absolutely. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}( $exp$(\frac{(-1)^n}{n})-1)$.

My Try:

Let $a_n=$exp$(\frac{(-1)^n}{n})-1$. I was going to use alternating series test because the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is alternating. But $\{|a_n|\}$ is not decreasing to $0$. So, I am stuck now. Can anybody please give me a hint?

Comment: Can you give a useful estimate for $\lvert e^x - 1 - x\rvert$?

Comment: Hint: Taylor's theorem shows that $e^t=1+t+E(t)$ where $|E(t)|\le cx^2$ for $|x|\la 1$.

Comment: If $|a_n|$ doesn't decrease to 0, then the series can't converge, absolutely or conditionally.

Comment: "But $|a_n|$  is not decreasing to $0$ ": are you sure ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Pretty sure, since $|a_n|\to0$ but the sequence $|a_n|$ is not decreasing.

Comment: @Teepeemm Not true, consider $a_{2n}=2^{-n}$, $a_{2n+1}=0$.

Comment: @Did I and others (I presume) were focusing on "to 0".  You (and OP) are correct however that the sequence is not decreasing, which would be the easiest way to prove convergence.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convergence of $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\exp\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right)-1\right)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632697/convergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-left-exp-left-frac-1nn-right-1-righ)

Comment: I think the what is linked as a duplicate target ought to be the duplicate of this post on this page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may just use the fact that, as $x \to 0$, using the Taylor expansion,
$$
e^x=1+x+O(x^2)
$$ giving, for some $n_0\geq1$,
$$
\sum_{n\geq n_0}\left(\exp \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right)-1\right)=\sum_{n\geq n_0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+\sum_{n\geq n_0}O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right).
$$ The latter series is absolutely convergent and the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n\geq n_0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ is conditionally convergent. It gives the desired result.

Comment: Why do you sum starting from $n_0$ and not from $1$?

Comment: I posted a question related to my comment above https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2849127/is-this-use-of-big-o-notation-for-proving-convergence-correct/2849610

Answer (score 2):

**PART 1:**  ESTABLISHING CONVERGENCE

From the Mean Value Theorem we have

$$e^{(-1)^n/n}-1=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+e^{\xi_n}\frac{1}{n^2}$$

for $0<|\xi_n|<\frac{1}{n}$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(e^{(-1)^n/n}-1\right)&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+e^{\xi_n}\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \tag 1
\end{align}$$

we recall that the alternating harmonic series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}=\log 2$ converges.   And we note that since $|e^{\xi_n}|<e$ for $0<|\xi_n|<\frac{1}{n}$, then the series

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{\xi_n}\frac{1}{n^2} &\le e\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\\\\
&=\frac{\pi^2\,e}{6}
\end{align}$$

also converges.   Finally,  since the sum of two convergent series is a convergent series, the series on the left-hand side of $(1)$ converges.

---

**PART 2:**  SHOWING CONVERGENCE IS CONDITIONAL

Now, we observe that the series of absolute values is bounded below as

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|e^{(-1)^n/n}-1\right|&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+e^{\xi_n}\frac{1}{n^2}\right|\\\\
&\ge \frac12\,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}
\end{align}$$

which diverges since the harmonic series diverges.  Thus, the series of interest is not absolutely convergent, only conditionally convergent.